# How to remove poi when using ImageMapType's getTileUrl method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

I am trying to remove the poi when Modifying the Map Type Registry. The issue I am having is that when I use ImageMapType's getTileUrl method, the styles I add to options dissapear. Please take a look at this sample:

```
 map.setOptions({
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: ["Map", 'VFR', 'IFR Low', 'Satellite'],
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
    },
    mapTypeId: "Map", //If I remove this line of code, the poi dissapear, else they appear
    styles : [
      { 
        "elementType": "all",
        "featureType": "poi",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  });

 
  map.mapTypes.set(
    "Map",
    new google.maps.ImageMapType({
      getTileUrl: (tileCoord, tileZoom) =>
        `https://mt.google.com/vt/lyrs=p&x=${tileCoord.x}&y=${tileCoord.y}&z=${tileZoom}`,
      tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
      name: 'Map',
      maxZoom: 21

    })
  );
```

My question is how can I remove the poi when using ImageMapType's getTileUrl?

Thanks in advance.